# solving linear differential equation with non diagonalizeable matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, diagonalization

I want to solve

$$
\dot{\begin{pmatrix}C_1(t)\\C_2(t)\\C_3(t)\end{pmatrix}}
=
A\cdot\begin{pmatrix}C_1(t)\\C_2(t)\\C_3(t)\end{pmatrix}+\vec{b}(x)
=
\begin{pmatrix}0&a&b\\-a&0&c\\-b&-c&0\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}C_1(t)\\C_2(t)\\C_3(t)\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}0\\V_{21}cos(wt)e^{w_{21}t}\\V_{31}cos(wt)e^{w_{31}t}\end{pmatrix}
$$

however $A$ is not diagonalizeable. It has no eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Is there still a way to solve this ?

Comment: Rodrigues formula exponentiate 3 by 3 skew symmetric:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747065/obtaining-the-rodrigues-formula
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879351/matrix-exponential-of-a-skew-symmetric-matrix-without-series-expansion

Comment: thanks. got it now.