# how to compute Riemannian logarithm and exponential on SO(3)

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

I am reading some papers involve some matrix computations on $SO(3)$, I want to know how to compute the matrix logarithm/exponential in the Riemannian logarithm/exponential of $SO(3)$:
$$\log _A(B)= A \log \left(A^{\top} B\right)$$,
$$Exp_A(V)= A \exp \left(A^{\top} V\right)$$
where $A,B \in SO(3)$, and $A^\top V$ is skrew symmetric.

Is there any reference I can refer to?

Comment: see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747065/obtaining-the-rodrigues-formula

Comment: Thanks! it solves my problem!