# The sigular case of matrix logarithm and exponential for rotation matrix

Tags: lie-groups, matrix-equations

This is the continuous question of [how to compute Riemannian logarithm and exponential on SO(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805060/how-to-compute-riemannian-logarithm-and-exponential-on-so3)

According to [Terse Notes on Riemannian Geometry](https://www.sci.utah.edu/%7Efletcher/RiemannianGeometryNotes.pdf) (Example 4.7.), the matrix exponential w.r.t. $SO(3)$ is
$$
\exp (X)= \begin{cases}I, & \theta=0, \\ I+\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} X+\frac{1-\cos \theta}{\theta^2} X^2, & \theta \in(0, \pi)\end{cases}
$$
where $\theta=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}\left(X^T X\right)}$, and $X$ is skrew symmetric.

The matrix logarithm on $SO(3)$ is
$$
\log (R)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0, & \theta=0, \\
\frac{\theta}{2 \sin \theta}\left(R-R^{\top}\right) & |\theta| \in(0, \pi)
\end{array}\right.
$$
wehre $\operatorname{tr}(R)=2 \cos \theta+1$ and $R \in SO(3)$.

So, what about $\theta=\pi$ for matrix logarithm and exponential?

I think the above expression of exponential is also valid for $\theta=\pi$. but I don't know how to deal with the case of $\theta=\pi$ for the logarithm